# Push Notification com Firebase + regras de negócio

Tags: ionic, firebase, push-notification

Tenho que receber push notification do firebase, mas não são para todos os celulares que essas notificações serão enviadas. Meu app checa alterações em contratos, o usuário informa um número de CPF e o app busca no banco de dados informações sobre os contratos sob esse CPF, e esses contratos são alterados com frequência. Então eu queria que o usuário recebesse notificação no app quando algum contrato sob o CPF informado fosse modificado. Já pensei enviar push para todos os celulares, e de alguma forma no Ionic mostrar executar o push somente se o CPF for do usuário, mas achei muito errada essa solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta o seguinte, no momento em o usuário se registrar tem como gerar um token do fcm pra ele:

```
this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
  console.log(token);
  //Aqui você pode armazenar esse token em algum lugar (Local Storage) e depois na hora de criar o usuário você passa o mesmo.
});
```

Depois na hora de enviar o push é só percorrer a lista de CPF que você quer, pegar e enviar as mensagens de acordo com o token de cada um.

Referencias:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Entendi, mais ou menos. Como no firebase eu relacionaria o token que foi cadastrado para criar esse vinculo de token e cpf??  Vamos supor: app gerou um token = 34 , app que possui o CPF 2222, criou usuário pelo token gerado. Como no firebase vou saber que para o CPF 222 tenho que enviar para o app de token 34?

Comment: Ah, acho que agora entendi. Eu geraria um token no fcm, depois na hora de criar a conta eu gravaria esse token la no firebase, depois eu varreria o documento de tokens e enviaria para os cadastrados para aquele CPF? É isso? Acho que dá certo mesmo. No firebase dá pra fazer isso com functions, neh? Vou dar uma lida nas referências que você me passou. Vlws.

Comment: Isso mesmo hehe, da uma olhada. É só vc atrelar o token pra um usuário